# Start VPN from SSIS package?

Tags: windows, ssis, vpn, windows-server-2012, ssis-2012

Using SSIS I need to retrieve data from a server outside my network/domain.
I can only get to this server through a VPN.
I created 2 packages:

1. StartVPN - using some VB this package starts the VPN. Works great. :)
2. Import Files - This package is called from StartVPN and should import some data.

When I run package 2 directly with the VPN already started this package runs great.
When I run package 2 from package 1 without the task that starts the VPN but with the VPN manually started this package runs great.

However, if I call this package from package 1 it fails with the error:
The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "MyConnection" failed with error code 0xC0202009. 
It does not matter if the VPN was already started or not.

How can I runn package 2 with the VPN only running during execution of the package?

Comment: Sometimes the actual error lies somewhere and the error message directs us to look at something else. We end up wasting time in this process as the error message diverted us - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ramoji/archive/2009/03/10/the-acquireconnection-method-call-to-the-connection-manager-failed-with-error-code-0xc0202009.aspx

Comment: Can you please add entire error message in  your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it! 
I needed to add a wait between package1 (starting the VPN) and package2 (doing the import)
After setting up the VPN, package1 was made to wait 5 secs before continuing. Now everything works swell :)

SO: Package 1 containg a VB scriptask for starting up the (existing) VPN:

```
Dim VPNConnectionName As String = "MyVPN"
Dim VPNlogin As String = "MyUser"
Dim VPNPassword As String = "MyPass"

Shell("RASDIAL " & Chr(34) & VPNConnectionName & Chr(34) & " " & VPNlogin & " " & VPNPassword, vbNormalFocus)
        '
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

Then from package1 call package 2 for the actual import

And  a VB scripttask for closing the VPN:

```
Dim VPNConnectionName As String = "MyConnection"

Shell("RASDIAL " & Chr(34) & VPNConnectionName & Chr(34) & " /DISCONNECT", vbNormalFocus)
            '
Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```