# How to put Open VPN process in an SSIS task control flow

Tags: sql-server, vba, ssis, vpn, openvpn

I'm learning how to use SSIS to create auto scheduled tasks. Everything went smoothly until the security policy has changed. Before whenever I wanted to connect to database, I just type in IP address, username and password in SSIS connection manager. **Now** I need to open up OpenVPN first which is still a manual process. So I really would like to put this bit into an SSIS task flow.

I had a search on Stackoverflow and over some other websites. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529188/start-vpn-from-ssis-package) in stackoverflow. This example gives the idea that we can use VBA to setup the link. However that example shows we need a VPN connection name and VPN username which I don't really have and don't know where to find. Everytime I just right click on a .ovpn file and choose **start openvpn on this config file**. Also when I open that .ovpn file there is no command indicating which is my connection name or user name. Here is what it looks like when I open it up (there is no `-auth-user-pass` thing in this file and I can use this file without having to specify it):

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote a website here 1111
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
verb 3

ca ca.crt
cert office.crt
key office.key
askpass login.txt
```

Is it possible to find my connection name and user name? If I don't need connection name and user name, can I still write up VBA to build up an auto connection process?

I also notice there is an `execute process task` in SSIS. Is it possible that I can make use of it (because in my understanding obviously I use openvpn.exe to execute a .ovpn file)?

Please correct me if I'm saying something wrong since I'm new to both VPN and SSIS. And much appreciate for whoever can help me with this.

Comment: umm.. see the last line "askpass login.txt" ? I think... search your computer for that text file where you should find the username and password... I think... maybe ;)

Comment: @Ricardo C There was no that line before and I had to copy and paste my password to a black prompt window every time. So I created that file and it only contains a password (learned that from someone else from other website). Thanks for your comment:)

Comment: "my password" you said? as in my windows password? man, it sounds like your OpenVPN is using Active directory for the authentication. This being the case you username and password is no other but the one you use to logon into your computer, your windows username and password.

Comment: Oh, sorry it's not really "my password". It is just a password to login OpenVPN and totally different one. Sorry about my misleading statement

Comment: The SO question/answer you linked to uses a different VPN tool (judging by the code, something called RASDIAL).  So the parameters being used there are not relevant if you intend to use OpenVPN.  Have you checked the docs for OpenVPN for command-line options?  Is there a way to launch it while specifying a config file?  If you can get that far, then Shell-ing that command-line in an SSIS Script Task will work, leaving you with the problem of entering a password.  Please update the question with any further info.

Comment: @SebTHU thanks for your response. Here is the doc I found in OpenVPN https://www.dropbox.com/s/18x67l2atlpvi29/openvpn.8.html?dl=0 . I'm not sure where I should be looking at. Can you have a look at this please? Thanks

Comment: It's the second entry under Options: openvpn [path to config file].  That should start OpenVPN with your config file.  To figure out how the security works, you'll have to read through the document to find out how the settings in your particular config file affect things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with my IT colleague, I think I solve the problem. Here are my answer and opinion to this question, and please correct me if I am wrong.

I think opening a VPN automatically is a case by case issue. In this case I am still using **Execute Process Task** in SSIS. Inside the task editor, what we are executing is not openVPN.exe, it should be a batch file. In the batch file (.bat file) it contains the command of opening .ovpn file with OpenVPN.exe

The process below gives you more detailed info.

The command line is what I use in the batch file:

```
@echo off
CD /D "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config"
start openvpn client.ovpn
TIMEOUT /T 10
exit
```

In SSIS execute process task 
[image]

Hopefully this is useful

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about OpenVPN, but I ran into a similar problem a while back with a server that insisted on an SSH tunnel using PuTTY as the only allowed connection method.

People who put these policies in place never think of the impact on SSIS, especially for unattended processing.

The solution I found was:

1. Find the command-line equivalent to the PuTTy client (which is called plink)
2. Have the detailed documentation to hand, because this is really difficult.
3. Have the SSIS package start plink.exe, passing various parameters (Note: don't use the Execute Process task, as that waits for the process to exit: launch the process in a Script task, and get the handle of plink.exe's ProcessID).
4. After a wait, have another Script task in SSIS connect to the plink process' InputBuffer, "typing in" a password.  Yes, insecure and clunky, though you can store SSIS project parameters encrypted (this obviously requires SSIS 2012 or later)

   5. The SSIS package can now connect to the server and do data stuff, as if it was a normal server without stupid access requirements.
   6. At the end of the package, kill the plink.exe process.

Bear in mind, also, that on unattended execution (e.g. when scheduled in a job), your package will be running in a *different* security context from the one you work in to develop the package (depending on the SSIS service settings).  If your access to OpenVPN has any dependency on ActiveDirectory, you may have to set up another OpenVPN account for the SSIS service's Logon user.

If this sounds horrible, nightmarishly complicated and unstable, it's because it is.  Really, the TL;DR version is: tell whoever administers the server that if they really want you to access it using SSIS, they should put some more sensible access policy in place.